# Is my use of a MySQL User Defined Variable reliable?

Tags: mysql

I've read a lot about how unsafe it is to read/write a MySQL User Defined Variable in the same statement.  This use case seems pretty simple, but I wanted to see what others think.

Here I have a table with score and weight.  I'm doing a ranking, so I order by score and do a running sum of the weights, until I get to the number I want.  Because I'm using Hibernate, I can't do a subselect in the FROM clause.

```
SELECT 
    score, weight, @val := score
FROM 
    tmp, (SELECT @runtot := 0) init
HAVING
    (@runtot := @runtot + weight) <= (7)
ORDER BY score;
```

This seems fairly safe since the eval and comparison are part of the same expression.  Then @val will be set to the last score evaluated, and I can just do a 'SELECT @VAL' to get the last value.

Is this a safe use of a User Defined Variable?

Comment: the having clause is not intended to be used instead of a where clause.

Comment: You're right, of course -- I had gotten in the habit of using HAVING because before I was calculating the running total in the SELECT, and couldn't reference it in the WHERE... fixed.

Comment: Actually, this is a contrived example.  When using my actual query with filters in the WHERE clause, putting the runtot in the WHERE clause returned the wrong result.  I had to artificially create a GROUP BY to get Hibernate to let me use the HAVING clause.